# How to reset password for admin account in IBM websphere 6.1?

Tags: websphere, admin, websphere-traditional

We have an admin account for our websphere application version 6.1 ! User admin account is wwsadmin. We have forgot the password of this admin account and not able to login into our console. Can anybody tell how we can reset the password of this admin account. I tried google and applied some steps but no help. Anyone who have worked as a admin for websphere 6.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn off admin security:

1. Connect to wsadmin:
   `$WAS_HOME/bin/wsadmin.bat -connType NONE`
2. Turn off security:
   Jacl: `wsadmin> securityoff`
   Jython: `wsadmin> securityoff()`
3. Restart the server (server1 in this case):
   `$WAS_HOME/bin/stopServer.bat server1`
   `$WAS_HOME/bin/startServer.bat server1`

Then, connect to the admin console and set new admin user credentials and turn security back on:

1. Start the server
2. Open the admin console and go to **Security -> Global Security**
3. Check the **Enable administrative security** box
4. Use the **Security Configuration Wizard** to set new admin user credentials.

These steps will work for WebSphere versions 6.0 and up.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the steps. I am using Linux server. For that also, I have to try these steps like security off and then start and stop and then go to console and add a new admin user.

Comment: Not much different for Linux, just use `*.sh` instead of `*.bat`

Comment: Hi aguibert, I did some steps and I guess password changed worked, I tried this in my one environment. Can you also tell how can I add a admin to my websphere if bymistake admin ID is deleted ?

Comment: Just use the same steps to create an admin user with the same ID as before

Comment: @VKS great, glad it worked.  Since this answer resolved your question, it would be appreciated if you could mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

or you could edit the security.xml file

```
<security enabled="false" ....
```