# IBM Websphere security issue - Password reset

Tags: configuration, websphere, settings, credentials

I have an issue with IBM Websphere,
We forgot our password and I followed the topic I found here in the forum to reset admin password.

[How to reset password for admin account in IBM websphere 6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592030/how-to-reset-password-for-admin-account-in-ibm-websphere-6-1)

Issue I have is when I disable security, I get into the websphere console but have NO option to get into security tab. No tab available except "tasks", so I cannot enable security nor reset the admin user there.

Also, after this, I cannot put security on again. I keep getting the login page with no password.
I tried the script with securityon instead of securityoff (sounds logical to me) but now it requests user password to do so...

If I manually edit the security.xml to put security enabled="true", I get a startup error...

---

UPDATE 1

There was an issue loading applications, so that's the reason why I could not get the menu on the left. However, I could not find any solution to it, and decided to restore the system.

Now I can get the menu list, but face another error when I try to reset the admin user with the wizard, at the last steps here is the message error I get :

SECJ7305E: Found other virtual member manager repository configurations. Only the built-in virtual member manager file-based repository is supported through the wizard

This actually blocks me, and I cannot go further.
I tried to run the wizard without activating security as well, but not working either.

I do not want to mess with user repositories as some repo's are configured... I just would like to reset the admin password :(

Anybody faced this issue? Any help/idea is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: In top right of admin console, make sure the View: option is set to 'all tasks'.   Turning off administrative security shouldn't make task tabs disappear.  I should also point out that WebSphere 6.1 has been out of service for a long time.  Please update to supported versions 8.5.5 or 9.0 when you can.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks for your reply. There was an issue loading applications so now I'm further in the process. I will edit my post